# smallest 3 elements in 2- dimensional matrix

Tags: c, matrix

Here i have some problems with find smallest 3 elements in 2- dimensional matrix in C

here is my code:

```
for (i=0; i<r; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<c; j++) {
        if (m[i][j] < min1) {
            min1 = m[i][j];
            indexi_1 = i;
            indexj_1 = j;
        }
        if (m[i][j] < min2 && indexi_1 != i && indexj_1 != j) {
            min2 = m[i][j];
            indexi_2 = i;
            indexj_2 = j;
        }
    }
    for (j=0; j<c; j++) {
        if (m[i][j] < min3 && m[i][j] != m[indexi_1][indexj_1] && m[i][j] != m[indexi_2][indexj_2]) {
            min3 = m[i][j];
            indexi_3 = i;
            indexj_3 = j;
        }
    }
}
```

with matrix like this

```
int m[r][c] = {{33,  4, 23,  2}, {5,  3, 24, 16}, {8, 31,  7,  4},{10,  5,  2,  6}};
```

getting this output:

```
 Local minimum (value=2) - row=0, column=3.
 Local minimum (value=2) - row=3, column=2.
 Local minimum (value=4) - row=0, column=1.
```

so as you see here, the problem only with last min element, i think it doused because of index.

Comment: This is the pefect moment to start using a debugger, to trace the code step by step inspecting all relevant variable and doing so discover what is **really** happening "inside" the code. Because, you know, well, err .... -  SO is **not** a debugging service.

Comment: Possibly [a rubber duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You compare the third minimum against the values of *temporary* `min1` and `min2`. You must move the third loop after the outer `for` loop

```
for (i=0; i<r; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<c; j++) {
        if (m[i][j] < min1) {
            min1 = m[i][j];
            indexi_1 = i;
            indexj_1 = j;
        }
        if (m[i][j] < min2 && indexi_1 != i && indexj_1 != j) {
            min2 = m[i][j];
            indexi_2 = i;
            indexj_2 = j;
        }
    }
}

for (i=0; i<r; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<c; j++) {
        if (m[i][j] < min3 && m[i][j] != m[indexi_1][indexj_1] && m[i][j] != m[indexi_2][indexj_2]) {
            min3 = m[i][j];
            indexi_3 = i;
            indexj_3 = j;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the last loop will compare against the final first two minima.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
if (m[i][j] < min3 &&
    m[i][j] != m[indexi_1][indexj_1] &&
    m[i][j] != m[indexi_2][indexj_2])
```

You compare values instead of indices.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
if (m[i][j] < min3 && m[i][j] != m[indexi_1][indexj_1] && m[i][j] != m[indexi_2][indexj_2])
```

to

```
if (m[i][j] < min3 && (indexi_1 != i && indexj_1 != j) && (indexi_2 != i && indexj_2 != j))
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer in brief?